# Chartjs error : time scale: "time.format" is deprecated. Please use "time.parser" instead

Tags: angular, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I am using Chartjs for my project. Different versions I am using are: ChartJS 2.9.3, Chartjs-plugin-streaming 1.8.0, moment.js 2.24.0,chartjs-adapter-moment 0.1.1.
I plotting a realtime chart and I get this warning every second which is filling memory very fast.

> time scale: "time.format" is deprecated. Please use "time.parser" instead

My code is:

```js
    private chartPlotting() {
    this.Linecap.push(new Chart('canvas', {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Flow',
                lineTension: 0,
                data: [],
                borderColor: '#3cb371',
                fill: false
            },
            {
                label: 'Height',
                lineTension: 0,
                data: [],
                borderColor: '#FF0000',
                fill: false
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'realtime',
                    time: {
                        parser: 'false'
                    },
                    display: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 10,
                        stepSize: 5,
                        max: 500
                    }
                }],
            },
            plugins: {
                streaming: {
                    duration: 300000,
                    refresh: 1000,
                    delay: 2000,
                    pause: false,
                    ttl: undefined,
                    frameRate: 48,

                    onRefresh: function (Linecap) {
                        ///var data = []
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open('GET', url);
                        xhr.onload = function () {
                            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            Linecap.data.datasets[0].data.push({
                                x: Date.now(),
                                y: data[0]["yrData"]
                            });
                            Linecap.data.datasets[1].data.push({
                                x: Date.now(),
                                y: data[0]["Height"]
                            });
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

I tried to find out reason for this and came to know that may be in next version of chartJS i.e. 3.0.0 this problem will be removed. Is there any work around for getting rid of this error in 2.9.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to incompatible versions of the different libraries you're using.

The documentation of [chartjs-plugin-streaming](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-streaming) for example states the following:

> Version 1.8 requires Chart.js 2.7.x or 2.8.x.

**To get rid of the problem, you have two options.**

1. get rid of chartjs-plugin-streaming
2. downgrade Chart.js 2.9.3 to 2.8.0

**UPDATE**

With Angular 8, I recommend using [`ng2-charts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts), which is based on `Chart.js`. Further you should get rid of `chartjs-plugin-streaming` and implement related functionality by your own.

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/auto-update-ng-charts-yg38z3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Any other chart which can be used for real time charting with Angular 8? Downgrading 2.8.0 might bring some other trouble.

Comment: @braveYug: I updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Or upgrade to chartjs-plugin-streaming v1.9.0 which supports Chart.js 2.9

Answer (score 0):

6 months later it's still an open pull request on their repo. You can see the discussion and the long-pending fix [here](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming/pull/98).

If you don't want to downgrade or change libraries you can either use the fix locally yourself, or use one of the npm packages uploaded by contributors who got tired of waiting. I'm using `@taeuk-gang/chartjs-plugin-streaming`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was [fixed](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming/pull/98) in chartjs-plugin-streaming 1.9.0. Also, Chart.js 3.x is supported in the latest version [2.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming/releases).